# Linq get distinct list from nested list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a object something like this

```
List<Hotel> Hotels;

public class Hotel
{
  List<RoomType> RoomType;
}

public class RoomType
{
  Room Room;
}

public class Room
{
  int RoomId;
}
```

I want to end up with a list of Hotels but where the nested list of RoomType is distinct by the RoomId. That is, if the RoomId is already given for another Hotel I don't want to add the Hotel again. I have tried lots of solutions and tried MoreLinq, but all I can find is how to get a distinct inner-list.

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: I want a Porsche. :-) Joking aside: why not start with a simple `foreach`, then try to optimize ist, apply some Linq and if it is getting too complex, you should ask yourself _why_ you want it to be plain Linq?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the question; so basically you would like to select hotels to obtain a covering for all room ids which are present? This seems to be some hypergraph covering problem which perhaps cannot be solved with Linq only. Please clarify.

Comment: Also provide at least some input to reproduce please. P.s. I'd advise you to check [Capitalization Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Besides, as you have said _if the RoomId is already given for another Hotel I don't want to add the Hotel again_ do you really expect `roomId` to be unique for ALL hotels? Which doesn't actually make any sense to me tbh.

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to achieve? If you're trying to provide a list of hotels and their room offerings, why would you exclude a hotel from the list just because it has the same room id as another hotel?

Comment: The "Hotel" here is just an example class for clarification. I'm working with a completly other domain :) I'll try with some foreach-loops instead, just asked because I thought there might be something smart I didn't see. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you want to have a distinct list of `RoomId`s and for each one one `Hotel`:

```
var result = hotels.SelectMany(hotel => hotel.RoomType.Select(room => new { Id = room.RoomId, Hotel = hotel }))
                   .GroupBy(item => item.Id)
                   .Select(group => group.FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Thanks, almost. But it selects the Hotel for each RoomType and thus the same Hotel is selected multiple times.

Comment: @perene - I think that is what you asked for - a distinct list of Id's and a hotel for each (you can change the logic of the `.FirstOrDefault` for how to select the wanted `Hotel` for each Id